# How to replace elements in a list with elements in another list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have two lists that I generated "mergers" and "mergers18S"

The "mergers" list looks like:

```
    abundance forward reverse nmatch nmismatch nindel prefer accept
1         367       1       1     58         0      0      2   TRUE
2          69      60      20     57         0      0      2   TRUE
3          66      11       3     57         0      0      2   TRUE
4          60      12      37    108        71     28      1  FALSE
```

where each number in the first column corresponds to a DNA sequence listed after the table e.g.:

```
2 TACGAAGGGGGCTAGCGTTGCTCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGGGTGCGTAGGCGGGTCTTTAAGTCAGGGGTGAAATCCTGGAGCTCAACTCCAGAACTGCCTTTGATACTGAGGATCTTGAGTTCGGGAGAGGTGAGTGGAACTGCGAGTGTAGAGGTGAAATTCGTAGATATTCGCAAGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGGCTCACTGGCCCGATACTGACGCTGAGGCACGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAATGCCAGCCGTTAGTGGGTTTACTCACTAGTGGCGCAGCTAACGCTTTAAGCATTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGTCGCAAGATTA
```

The mergers18S list is the same format but in the "accept" column everything is TRUE.

I would like to replace all the FALSE elements under the accept column with their corresponding elements in mergers18

I tried mergers

```
[!mergers$accept,] <- mergers18S[!mergers$accept,]
```

but recieved

> Error in !mergers$accept : invalid argument type

because I think it is a list and not a data frame but the list loses it's formatting if I try to flatten it or turn it into a data frame.

Comment: `mergers[!mergers$accept,] <- mergers18S[!mergers$accept,]`?

Comment: FYI: this is certainly a `data.frame`, not a `list`. Indexing a `list` does not work with the comma-dimensions, that's reserved for `data.frame`, `matrix`, `array`, and other derivative structures.

Comment: @r2evans data.frames are lists at heart.

Comment: I know, but `data.frame`s are derived from `list`s, not the other way around. Put another way, you can index a `data.frame` as you would a `list`, but not the other way around. That's the point I was trying to make.

Comment: Right I think my problem is I am trying to treat a list as a data.frame.  Is there a way to accomplish this this replacement with a list?